Ubuntu is resetting fs.inotify.max_user_watches - how to make it stop messing with it?
I have fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 in cat /etc/sysctl.confcat
And still, every distro updrade, and "now-and-then" I have to do "sudo sysctl -p "

why is it not persistently saved ?  and reduced to 64k now and then?


Many system config files are migrating to directories for exactly this reason, and this includes sysctl.   Instead of editing an existing file that will be replaced on upgrade, create a new file in /etc/sysctl.d/
Likely this setting is already set in /etc/sysctl.d/30-nepomuk-inotify-limit.conf so you should create your file with a higher priority name (31? 99?) so that it overwrites the existing value being set.  (So maybe use 99-local.conf )
(Note: the README.sysctl file in that directory says the filename is not important, but in the case of collisions like this, that isn't completely correct.  I consider this oversight to be a bug in the README.)

thank you, this sounds perfectly reasonable :)
